# YouTube query function not working for my js bot discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, discord.js

I need help with the query part in this

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

 const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
 const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 const query = command.slice(command.search(' '), command.search('-'));
 if (command === 'ping') {
  message.channel.send('pong!');
 } else if (command === 'joke') {
  message.channel.send('Your life');
 } else if (command === 'youtube') {
  message.channel.send('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=' + query);
  message.channel.send(query);
 } else if (command === 'commands') {
  message.channel.send('commands so far are +ping, +joke, +youtube, +commands');
 }
});
```

the error is this

```
(node:15016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\kalar\Desktop\JavaPr\JS_Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:15016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15016) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I did this before I changed and I would just send the YouTube link instead of a query which i'm trying to make.

```
else if (command === 'youtube') {
  message.channel.send('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=' + query);
```

Comment: What is going wrong? Did you get an error? What is the actual problem? What does "I need help" mean?

Comment: srry i forgot to put the error cus im kinda busy ill add it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `query` variable.

```js
// this is overly complicated and will not work:
const query = command.slice(command.search(' '), command.search('-'));

// instead:
const query = args.join(' ');
```

Also, on this line:

```js
message.channel.send('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=' + query);
```

You should use the [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) function.

```js
message.channel.send(
 encodeURI(`https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${query}`)
);
```